# How Can I create a Hive Table on top of a Parquet File

Tags: hive

Facing issue on creating hive table on top of parquet file. Can someone help me on the same.? I have read many articles and followed the guidelines but not able to load a parquet file in Hive Table.

Comment: Share what you have tried and what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

According "[Using Parquet Tables in Hive](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html#parquet_hive)" it is often useful to create the table as an external table pointing to the location where the files will be created, if a table will be populated with data files generated outside of Hive.

```
hive> create external table parquet_table_name (<yourParquetDataStructure>)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/<yourPath>/<yourParquetFile>';
```